# WooCommerce order emails being sent before payment is complete

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

On my `WooCommerce` store, I have the [WooCommerce PayPal Payments](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-paypal-payments/) plugin installed.

Here is an image of my current payment structure:

[image]

Now, when I click on the "Pay with PayPal" button, the PayPal modal pops up which prompts me to log into PayPal. If I wait a few seconds, and input nothing in the modal, an email comes through saying "thank you for your order".

In short, the WooCommerce new order email gets triggered, even though the payment details haven't been entered. If I then close the modal and refresh the checkout page, I'm still asked for payment (normally on successful payment and order, you'll get redirected to a thank you / summary page).

Then, when logging in as an admin, I can see the new order come through which states the order is paid already.

Since I've enabled the PayPal Payments plugin, the yellow button has replaced the default "place order" button that `WooCommerce` provides. Initially, I was thinking on click of the yellow button, maybe the default button is being clicked too (because it's still in the markup).

The default button has the markup of:

```html
<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order">Place order</button>
```

And I have hidden this via CSS using:

```css
#place_order {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

With `pointer-events: none;` I am trying to prevent this button from clicking, if that is what's causing this.

However, the emails still get triggered when payment isn't complete?

Any idea's on what may be happening here? There are also nothing in WooCommerce logs that I can check, no logs get generated.

**Edit:**

I have been reading the following [thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-still-receives-ipn-and-ptd-and-sends-out-2-duplicated-order-emails-2/) and noticed the poster said they "*disabled IPN in woocommerce settings*". I was thinking maybe disabling this in my settings will prevent it from sending the order emails (and then when the `IPN` is sent and received by PayPal, the email will get triggered). But, I cannot see in settings where I can turn `IPN` off? I'm on `WooCommerce Version 5.8.0`.

Comment: Hey Freddy, I have checked the plugin support and I have found the one solution I think it may work for you.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/paid-orders-sending-on-hold-and-processing-emails/

Comment: Hi @ZealousWeb - The above solution is to stop certain emails (which can be done via WooCommerce > emails anyway). What I'm trying to figure out is why my "completed order" emails are triggering before payment is even made. Similar thread here, but no real answers: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/order-via-paypal-sends-new-order-mail-before-completing-payment-in-paypal/

Comment: _"But, I cannot see in settings where I can turn IPN off? I'm on WooCommerce Version 5.8.0."_ - WooCommerce -> Settings -> Checkout -> Paypal -> IPN email notifications

Comment: Which version of the plugin you are using?

Comment: @GautamGolakiya - My `WooCommerce` version is `5.8.0`. My `WooCommerce PayPal Payments` plugin is version `1.6.1`.

Comment: @7uc1f3r - Right, I'm trying to use the `WooCommerce PayPal Payments` plugin because I'm looking to implement credit card payments also. However, upon looking at the IPN option (finally see it now) in `PayPal Standard`, the description under it says `Send notifications when an IPN is received from PayPal indicating refunds, chargebacks and cancellations.`.  This is fine. I would want this option enabled because I want the order emails to be sent after the IPN is received from PayPal (as that is after payment). Mine are currently triggering before payment.

Comment: You may find it helpful to consult the WooCommerce support team about this.